# React: how to hide a component on certain pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How do i hide certain components on certain pages in my app?
Specifically I need to hide Navbar and Header from the Settings page.

in App.js i set up a router:

```
<div>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Header/>                               <- header and navbar are here
        <Navbar/>
        <Route exact path = "/" component= { Data } />
        <Route path = "/available-data" component= { Data } />
        <Route path = "/devices" component= { Devices } />
        <Route path = "/contacts" />
        <Route path = "/chat" />
        <Route path = "/settings" component = { Settings } />  <- i need to remove them from here 
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Header and Navbar are used in every component except in Settings. How do i go about removing/hiding them?

All three of the files are function components with useState hooks(if they even have state) if it matters :)

Comment: You need to modify the structure of your layout ... In the above example your Header andNavbar is outside the scope of Routes

Comment: Here's the structure you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Ajith thank you, moved them outside the Switch component

Comment: @ Chris G it works now! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can render a second switcher component to only route to pages with the header and navbar UI.

```
// in App.js

<div>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
      <Route path='/' ><UiRouter /></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>


// in UiRouter.js

export default function UiRouter() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Data} />
        <Route path="/available-data" component={Data} />
        <Route path="/devices" component={Devices} />
        <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
        <Route path="/chat" component={Chat}/>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, as Ajith mentioned, you should not have the components that you want to render for each route (Header and Navbar) inside the Switch component.